# How to weight clip in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am coding a wgan in tensorflow on mnist dataset and it works well but I am finding it difficult to clip weights of discriminator model `[-0.01,0.01]` in tensorflow. In [keras](https://github.com/eriklindernoren/Keras-GAN/blob/master/wgan/wgan.py) we can do weight clipping using.

```
for l in self.discriminator.layers:
    weights = l.get_weights()
    weights = [np.clip(w, -self.clip_value, self.clip_value) for w in weights]
    l.set_weights(weights)
```

I have found a tensorflow doc for [weight clipping discrimantor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/gan/features/clip_discriminator_weights)

```
tf.contrib.gan.features.clip_discriminator_weights(
    optimizer,
    model,
    weight_clip
)
```

Other than this there is not much is given to how use this function.

```
#my tf code
def generator(z):
    h=tf.nn.relu(layer_mlp(z,"g1",[10,128]))
    prob=tf.nn.sigmoid(layer_mlp(h,"g2",[128,784]))
    return prob


def discriminator(x):
    h=tf.nn.relu(layer_mlp(x,"d1",[784,128]))
    logit=layer_mlp(h,"d2",[128,1])
    prob=tf.nn.sigmoid(logit)
    return prob

G_sample=generator(z)
D_real= discriminator(x)
D_fake= discriminator(G_sample)


D_loss = tf.reduce_mean(D_real) - tf.reduce_mean(D_fake)
G_loss = -tf.reduce_mean(D_fake)

for epoch in epochs:
    #training the model
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding to Yaakov's answer, you can use tf.clip_by_value with trainable_variables as shown in this repo https://github.com/hcnoh/WGAN-tensorflow2

```
for w in model.discriminator.trainable_variables:
  w.assign(tf.clip_by_value(w, -clip_const, clip_const))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use below function to implement clipping in tensorflow.

```
tf.clip_by_value(
    t,
    clip_value_min,
    clip_value_max,
    name=None
)
```

Please refer to below links on how to implement it in your code.

- https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/clip_by_value
- https://github.com/wiseodd/generative-models/blob/master/GAN/wasserstein_gan/wgan_tensorflow.py